Is it possible to aggregate grouped rows in AG Grid?
Some context:
I'm working on a React.js frontend app, using the AgGridReact component. I've managed to get various custom aggregations working, default aggs working, etc. In a typical scenario like grouping by a column then aggregating another column, this works, and I see the aggregate value at the top (in this case a simple integer):

I am using the multipleColumns option for groupDisplayType Notice the 6 in the cell above the first row in the second column.
Sometimes however it's useful for our users to nest groupings, say group by one column, then another. In this case, they might still be interested in seeing an aggregation for the grouped column (like a count of unique elements):

I am using the multipleColumns option for groupDisplayType. Notice the first cell under the second group is now empty, despite applying the Count agg to the column. I've scoured the internet for this and haven't been able to find a direct answer to this. Is this possible?
UPDATE: Found this question posted in Github too without resolution.

I don't see a problem here. In fact we have done a whole bunch of customisations in our application too.
Same as you are defining an aggregate method for the first grouped column, enable the row-grouping for second column and then define custom aggregate method which will just match the values and return you the count. You can refer this for more details

We do have standard and custom aggregations defined for all of our columns. The problem becomes when a column becomes a rowgroup - it loses its aggregation cell up at the top of the column; from what I've seen I don't think this is possible, unless I'm misunderstanding you.
